# npm/yarn install working only locally but not in docker-compose

Tags: reactjs, docker, npm, docusaurus, npm-check-updates

I was working on the docs of our firm with docusaurus and trying to clone the Repo and start our task.json (vscode) script docker-compose: dev up, that basically runs our docker-compose-dev.yml. If I did that directly I would receive on docker thousands of `npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EIO: i/o error,`. When I check my node_modules after this thousand errors I've some of node_modules there, but definitely not all of them.

I've seen this error around here, but all solutions given are not applicable to me.

**
I'm sorry if I'm giving to little or too much info, it's my first post here, also the project is from the firm that I work on, it's a private project, so I can't share the repo**

the docker-compose-dev.yml file:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  docusaurus:
    container_name: ...
    image: node:20
    working_dir: /app
    command: bash
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - '8080:3000'
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
```

If I did npm install and then our script, it would function normally, but we don't want to install npm locally, we want to run on docker. I did find a one solution that 'works':

`volumes: - ./:/app - /app/node_modules`

unfortunately that doesn't work for us because it installs the node_modules in a volume but not locally, we need the node_modules locally because of husky that use them in the pre-commits to github.

what I've already tried:

1. delete node_modules
2. clear cache and then install (both npm and yarn)
3. delete the lock files (yarn and npm)
4. add --network-host to the install
5. uninstall completely and install docker
6. update node, change node package on the docker-file.yml
7. entrypoint
8. npm install -g / npm update
9. disable experimental features
10. sudo
11. --force, --legacy-peer-deps

I've tried all this solutions all mixed and separated, none of them worked, the error when I run npm install:

```
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EIO: i/o error, open '/app/node_modules/@babel/runtime-corejs3/node_modules/core-js-pure/es/string/starts-with.js'
2023-07-04 09:43:52 npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EIO: i/o error, open '/app/node_modules/core-js/es/string/strike.js'
2023-07-04 09:43:52 npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EIO: i/o error, open '/app/node_modules/@babel/runtime-corejs3/node_modules/core-js-pure/es/string/virtual/starts-with.js'
2023-07-04 09:43:52 npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EIO: i/o error, open '/app/node_modules/docusaurus-theme-openapi/node_modules/faker/lib/locales/de/name/prefix.js'
2023-07-04 09:43:52 npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EIO: i/o error, open '/app/node_modules/docusaurus-theme-openapi/node_modules/@faker-js/faker/lib/locales/pt_BR/name/prefix.js'
2023-07-04 09:43:52 npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EIO: i/o error, open '/app/node_modules/docusaurus-plugin-openapi/node_modules/@faker-js/faker/lib/locales/ja/address/postcode.js'
2023-07-04 09:43:52 npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EIO: i/o error, open '/app/node_modules/core-js/es/string/virtual/strike.js'
2023-07-04 09:43:52 npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EIO: i/o error, open '/app/node_modules/@babel/runtime-corejs3/node_modules/core-js-pure/features/instance/starts-with.js'
2023-07-04 09:43:52 npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EIO: i/o error, open '/app/node_modules/docusaurus-theme-openapi/node_modules/monaco-editor/dev/vs/basic-languages/python/python.js'
2023-07-04 09:43:52 npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EIO: i/o error, open '/app/node_modules/docusaurus-theme-openapi/node_modules/@faker-js/faker/lib/locales/pt_PT/name/prefix.js'
2023-07-04 09:43:52 npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EIO: i/o error, open '/app/node_modules/docusaurus-theme-openapi/node_modules/faker/lib/locales/el/name/prefix.js'
2023-07-04 09:43:52 npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EIO: i/o error, open '/app/node_modules/docusaurus-plugin-openapi/node_modules/@faker-js/faker/lib/locales/ko/address/postcode.js'
2023-07-04 09:43:52 npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EIO: i/o error, open '/app/node_modules/core-js/features/string/strike.js'
2023-07-04 09:43:52 npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EIO: i/o error, open '/app/node_modules/@babel/runtime-corejs3/node_modules/core-js-pure/features/string/starts-with.js'
2023-07-04 09:43:52 [##################] - reify:rxjs: WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EIO: i/o error, op
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EIO: i/o error, open '/app/node_modules/docusaurus-theme-openapi/node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/basic-languages/python/python.js'
2023-07-04 09:43:52 npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EIO: i/o error, open '/app/node_modules/docusaurus-theme-openapi/node_modules/@faker-js/faker/lib/locales/ro/name/prefix.js'
2023-07-04 09:43:52 npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EIO: i/o error, open '/app/node_modules/docusaurus-theme-openapi/node_modules/faker/lib/locales/en/name/prefix.js'
2023-07-04 09:43:52 npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EIO: i/o error, open '/app/node_modules/docusaurus-plugin-openapi/node_modules/@faker-js/faker/lib/locales/lv/address/postcode.js'
2023-07-04 09:43:52 npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EIO: i/o error, open '/app/node_modules/core-js/features/string/virtual/strike.js'
2023-07-04 09:43:52 npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EIO: i/o error, open '/app/node_modules/@babel/runtime-corejs3/node_modules/core-js-pure/features/string/virtual/starts-with.js'
2023-07-04 09:43:52 npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EIO: i/o error, open '/app/node_modules/docusaurus-plugin-openapi/node_modules/faker/reports/coverage/lcov-report/lib/locales/pt_PT/cell_phone/formats.js.html'
2023-07-04 09:43:52 npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EIO: i/o error, open '/app/node_modules/docusaurus-theme-openapi/node_modules/@faker-js/faker/lib/locales/ru/company/prefix.js'
2023-07-04 09:43:52 npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EIO: i/o error, open '/app/node_modules/docusaurus-theme-openapi/node_modules/faker/lib/locales/es_MX/name/prefix.js'
2023-07-04 09:43:52 npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EIO: i/o error, open '/app/node_modules/docusaurus-plugin-openapi/node_modules/@faker-js/faker/lib/locales/nb_NO/address/postcode.js'
2023-07-04 09:43:52 npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EIO: i/o error, open '/app/node_modules/core-js/full/string/strike.js'
2023-07-04 09:43:52 [##################] | reify:rxjs: WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EIO: i/o error, op
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EIO: i/o error, open '/app/node_modules/@babel/runtime-corejs3/node_modules/core-js-pure/full/instance/starts-with.js'
2023-07-04 09:43:52 npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EIO: i/o error, open '/app/node_modules/docusaurus-theme-openapi/node_modules/@faker-js/faker/lib/locales/ru/name/prefix.js'
2023-07-04 09:43:52 npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EIO: i/o error, open '/app/node_modules/docusaurus-theme-openapi/node_modules/faker/lib/locales/es/name/prefix.js'
2023-07-04 09:43:52 npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EIO: i/o error, open '/app/node_modules/docusaurus-plugin-openapi/node_modules/@faker-js/faker/lib/locales/ne/address/postcode.js'
2023-07-04 09:43:52 npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EIO: i/o error, open '/app/node_modules/core-js/full/string/virtual/strike.js'
2023-07-04 09:43:52 npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EIO: i/o error, open '/app/node_modules/@babel/runtime-corejs3/node_modules/core-js-pure/full/string/starts-with.js'
```

```
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EIO: i/o error, open '/app/node_modules/docusaurus-plugin-openapi/node_modules/faker/reports/coverage/lib/locales/de/internet/index.html'
2023-07-04 09:44:20 [##################] | reify:monaco-editor: WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EIO: i/o [##################] | rei2023-07-04T07:44:20.316769181Z fy:monaco-editor: WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERRO[##################] | reify:monaco-editor: WARN tar T2023-07-04T07:44:20.316769181Z AR_ENTRY_ERRO[######2023-07-04T07:44:20.316769181Z ############] | reify:monaco-editor: WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERRO[##################] | reify:monaco-editor: 2023-07-04T07:44:20.316769181Z WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERRO[##################] | reify:monaco-editor: WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EIO: i/o e023-07-04T07:44:20.[##################] - reify:2023-07-04T07:44:20.316769181Z faker: http fetch GET 200 https://regi

2023-07-04 09:45:00 > husky install
2023-07-04 09:45:00 
2023-07-04 09:45:00 husky - Git hooks installed
2023-07-04 09:45:00 
2023-07-04 09:45:00 added 2037 packages, removed 1191 packages, changed 202 packages, and audited 2280 packages in 9m
2023-07-04 09:45:00 
2023-07-04 09:45:00 240 packages are looking for funding
2023-07-04 09:45:00   run `npm fund` for details
2023-07-04 09:45:01 
2023-07-04 09:45:01 79 vulnerabilities (67 moderate, 12 high)
2023-07-04 09:45:01 
2023-07-04 09:45:01 To address issues that do not require attention, run:
2023-07-04 09:45:01   npm audit fix
2023-07-04 09:45:01 
2023-07-04 09:45:01 To address all issues possible (including breaking changes), run:
2023-07-04 09:45:01   npm audit fix --force
2023-07-04 09:45:01 
2023-07-04 09:45:01 Some issues need review, and may require choosing
2023-07-04 09:45:01 a different dependency.
2023-07-04 09:45:01 
2023-07-04 09:45:01 Run `npm audit` for details.
2023-07-04 09:45:01 npm notice 
2023-07-04 09:45:01 npm notice New minor version of npm available! 9.6.7 -> 9.7.2
2023-07-04 09:45:01 npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v9.7.2
2023-07-04 09:45:01 npm notice Run npm install -g npm@9.7.2 to update!
2023-07-04 09:45:01 npm notice 
2023-07-04 09:45:01 2023-07-04T07:45:16.589460439Z [..................] - reify: timing arborist:c
npm ERR! Invalid Version: 
2023-07-04 09:45:16 
2023-07-04 09:45:16 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2023-07-04T07_45_04_369Z-debug-0.log
2023-07-04 09:45:16 2023-07-04T07:45:29.424632922Z [..................] \ idealTree: sill logfile 
npm ERR! Invalid Version: 
2023-07-04 09:45:29 
2023-07-04 09:45:29 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2023-07-04T07_45_18_526Z-debug-0.log
2023-07-04 09:45:29 2023-07-04T07:45:40.819886134Z [..................] - idealTree: timing arbori
npm ERR! Invalid Version: 
2023-07-04 09:45:40 
2023-07-04 09:45:40 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2023-07-04T07_45_31_755Z-debug-0.log
2023-07-04 09:45:40 2023-07-04T07:45:51.374165091Z [..................] \ idealTree: sill logfile 
npm ERR! Invalid Version: 
2023-07-04 09:45:51 
2023-07-04 09:45:51 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2023-07-04T07_45_42_083Z-debug-0.log
2023-07-04 09:45:51 2023-07-04T07:46:01.687325964Z [..................] - reify: timing arborist:c
npm ERR! Invalid Version: 
2023-07-04 09:46:01 
2023-07-04 09:46:01 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2023-07-04T07_45_53_267Z-debug-0.log
2023-07-04 09:46:01 2023-07-04T07:46:12.540142589Z [..................] \ reify: timing arborist:c
npm ERR! Invalid Version: 
2023-07-04 09:46:12 
2023-07-04 09:46:12 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2023-07-04T07_46_03_615Z-debug-0.log
2023-07-04 09:46:12 2023-07-04T07:46:22.680643648Z [..................] - reify: timing arborist:c
npm ERR! Invalid Version: 
2023-07-04 09:46:22 
2023-07-04 09:46:22 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2023-07-04T07_46_14_394Z-debug-0.log
2023-07-04 09:46:22 2023-07-04T07:46:32.634618437Z [..................] \ idealTree: sill logfile 
npm ERR! Invalid Version: 
2023-07-04 09:46:32 
2023-07-04 09:46:32 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2023-07-04T07_46_24_621Z-debug-0.log
2023-07-04 09:46:32 2023-07-04T07:46:43.095537556Z [..................] | idealTree: timing arbori
npm ERR! Invalid Version: 
2023-07-04 09:46:43 
2023-07-04 09:46:43 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2023-07-04T07_46_34_482Z-debug-0.log
2023-07-04 09:46:43 2023-07-04T07:46:53.533702532Z [..................] | idealTree: timing arbori
npm ERR! Invalid Version: 
2023-07-04 09:46:53 
2023-07-04 09:46:53 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2023-07-04T07_46_45_582Z-debug-0.log
2023-07-04 09:46:53 2023-07-04T07:47:06.040040171Z [..................] - reify: timing arborist:c
npm ERR! Invalid Version: 
2023-07-04 09:47:06 
2023-07-04 09:47:06 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2023-07-04T07_46_56_977Z-debug-0.log
2023-07-04 09:47:06 2023-07-04T07:47:19.329252070Z [..................] \ reify: timing arborist:c
npm ERR! Invalid Version: 
2023-07-04 09:47:19 
2023-07-04 09:47:19 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2023-07-04T07_47_10_468Z-debug-0.log
2023-07-04 09:47:19 2023-07-04T07:47:35.671847763Z [..................] \ idealTree: sill logfile 
npm ERR! Invalid Version: 
2023-07-04 09:47:35 
2023-07-04 09:47:35 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2023-07-04T07_47_27_338Z-debug-0.log
2023-07-04 09:47:35 2023-07-04T07:48:05.171706414Z [..................] | idealTree: sill logfile 
npm ERR! Invalid Version: 
2023-07-04 09:48:05 
2023-07-04 09:48:05 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2023-07-04T07_47_49_903Z-debug-0.log
2023-07-04 09:48:05 2023-07-04T07:48:25.606528332Z [..................] - reify: timing arborist:c
npm ERR! Invalid Version: 
2023-07-04 09:48:25 
2023-07-04 09:48:25 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2023-07-04T07_48_08_541Z-debug-0.log
2023-07-04 09:48:25 2023-07-04T07:48:37.140827685Z [..................] - reify: timing arborist:c
npm ERR! Invalid Version: 
2023-07-04 09:48:37 
2023-07-04 09:48:37 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2023-07-04T07_48_27_627Z-debug-0.log
2023-07-04 09:48:37 2023-07-04T07:48:47.053361637Z [..................] \ reify: timing arborist:c
npm ERR! Invalid Version: 
2023-07-04 09:48:47 
2023-07-04 09:48:47 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2023-07-04T07_48_39_074Z-debug-0.log
2023-07-04 09:48:47 2023-07-04T07:48:56.722007495Z [..................] \ idealTree: sill logfile 
npm ERR! Invalid Version: 
2023-07-04 09:48:56 
2023-07-04 09:48:56 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2023-07-04T07_48_48_616Z-debug-0.log
2023-07-04 09:48:56 2023-07-04T07:49:10.951669313Z [..................] \ idealTree: sill logfile 
npm ERR! Invalid Version: 
2023-07-04 09:49:10 
2023-07-04 09:49:10 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2023-07-04T07_48_58_543Z-debug-0.log
2023-07-04 09:49:11 2023-07-04T07:49:27.758654285Z [..................] - reify: timing arborist:c
npm ERR! Invalid Version: 
2023-07-04 09:49:27 
2023-07-04 09:49:27 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2023-07-04T07_49_15_081Z-debug-0.log
2023-07-04 09:49:27 2023-07-04T07:49:47.873483737Z [..................] - reify: timing arborist:c
npm ERR! Invalid Version: 
2023-07-04 09:49:47 
2023-07-04 09:49:47 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2023-07-04T07_49_30_762Z-debug-0.log
2023-07-04 09:49:47 2023-07-04T07:50:06.008481705Z [..................] - reify: timing arborist:c
npm ERR! Invalid Version: 
2023-07-04 09:50:06 
2023-07-04 09:50:06 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2023-07-04T07_49_51_017Z-debug-0.log
2023-07-04 09:50:06 2023-07-04T07:50:22.335203795Z [..................] - reify: timing arborist:c
npm ERR! Invalid Version: 
2023-07-04 09:50:22 
2023-07-04 09:50:22 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2023-07-04T07_50_08_372Z-debug-0.log
2023-07-04 09:50:22 2023-07-04T07:50:36.350825149Z [..................] - reify: timing arborist:c
npm ERR! Invalid Version: 
2023-07-04 09:50:36 
2023-07-04 09:50:36 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2023-07-04T07_50_25_820Z-debug-0.log
2023-07-04 09:50:36 2023-07-04T07:50:47.606812763Z [..................] \ reify: timing arborist:c
npm ERR! Invalid Version: 
2023-07-04 09:50:47 
2023-07-04 09:50:47 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2023-07-04T07_50_37_989Z-debug-0.log
2023-07-04 09:50:47 2023-07-04T07:50:58.131627644Z [..................] \ reify: timing arborist:c
npm ERR! Invalid Version: 
2023-07-04 09:50:58 
2023-07-04 09:50:58 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2023-07-04T07_50_49_835Z-debug-0.log
2023-07-04 09:50:58 2023-07-04T07:51:11.293427607Z [..................] - reify: timing arborist:c
npm ERR! Invalid Version: 
2023-07-04 09:51:11 
2023-07-04 09:51:11 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2023-07-04T07_51_00_310Z-debug-0.log
2023-07-04 09:51:11 2023-07-04
```

This is just part of the warns and errors cause as I said, it's thousand of errors

I've just tried the following and it gave a different error:

```
npm install -g npm-check-updates
ncu -u
npm install
```

the error:

```
# ncu -u
Upgrading /app/package.json
[====================] 15/15 100%

 @mdx-js/react                 ^1.6.22  →           ^2.3.0
 @redocly/cli          ^1.0.0-beta.128  →  ^1.0.0-beta.129
 prism-react-renderer           ^1.3.5  →           ^2.0.6
 react                         ^17.0.2  →          ^18.2.0
 react-dom                     ^17.0.2  →          ^18.2.0

Run npm install to install new versions.
# npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: ...
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.4 || ^17.0.0" from @docusaurus/core@2.4.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@docusaurus/core
npm ERR!   @docusaurus/core@"2.4.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /root/.npm/_logs/2023-07-04T07_59_11_404Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2023-07-04T07_59_11_404Z-debug-0.log
```

after that I tried to update react and gave the same error, so I tried to npm install --force, it appeared:

```
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @docusaurus/core@2.4.1
npm WARN Found: react@18.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@"^16.8.4 || ^17.0.0" from @docusaurus/mdx-loader@2.4.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@docusaurus/core/node_modules/@docusaurus/mdx-loader
npm WARN     @docusaurus/mdx-loader@"2.4.1" from @docusaurus/core@2.4.1
npm WARN     node_modules/@docusaurus/core
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"^16.8.4 || ^17.0.0" from @docusaurus/core@2.4.1
npm WARN node_modules/@docusaurus/core
npm WARN   @docusaurus/core@"2.4.1" from the root project
npm WARN   3 more (@docusaurus/preset-classic, ...)
npm WARN 
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@"^16.8.4 || ^17.0.0" from @docusaurus/core@2.4.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@docusaurus/core
npm WARN     @docusaurus/core@"2.4.1" from the root project
npm WARN     3 more (@docusaurus/preset-classic, ...)
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @docusaurus/core@2.4.1
npm WARN Found: react-dom@18.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/react-dom
npm WARN   peer react-dom@"^16.8.4 || ^17.0.0" from @docusaurus/mdx-loader@2.4.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@docusaurus/core/node_modules/@docusaurus/mdx-loader
npm WARN     @docusaurus/mdx-loader@"2.4.1" from @docusaurus/core@2.4.1
npm WARN     node_modules/@docusaurus/core
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react-dom@"^16.8.4 || ^17.0.0" from @docusaurus/core@2.4.1
npm WARN node_modules/@docusaurus/core
npm WARN   @docusaurus/core@"2.4.1" from the root project
npm WARN   3 more (@docusaurus/preset-classic, ...)
npm WARN 
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: react-dom@17.0.2
npm WARN node_modules/react-dom
npm WARN   peer react-dom@"^16.8.4 || ^17.0.0" from @docusaurus/core@2.4.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@docusaurus/core
npm WARN     @docusaurus/core@"2.4.1" from the root project
npm WARN     3 more (@docusaurus/preset-classic, ...)
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
```

and then after lots of this it came back to the thousand same error as in the beginning:

```
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EIO: i/o error, open '/app/node_modules/faker/reports/coverage/lcov-report/lib/locales/ko/index.html'
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EIO: i/o error, open '/app/node_modules/monaco-editor/monaco.d.ts'
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EIO: i/o error, open '/app/node_modules/faker/reports/coverage/lcov-report/lib/locales/ko/internet/index.html'
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EIO: i/o error, open '/app/node_modules/faker/reports/coverage/lcov-report/lib/locales/ko/lorem/index.html'
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EIO: i/o error, open '/app/node_modules/faker/reports/coverage/lcov-report/lib/locales/ko/name/index.html'
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EIO: i/o error, open '/app/node_modules/monaco-editor/dev/vs/base/browser/ui/codicons/codicon/codicon.ttf'
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EIO: i/o error, open '/app/node_modules/faker/reports/coverage/lcov-report/lib/locales/ko/phone_number/index.html'
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EIO: i/o error, open '/app/node_modules/faker/reports/coverage/lcov-report/lib/locales/nb_NO/address/index.html'
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EIO: i/o error, open '/app/node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/base/browser/ui/codicons/codicon/codicon.ttf'
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EIO: i/o error, open '/app/node_modules/faker/reports/coverage/lcov-report/lib/locales/nb_NO/company/index.html'
[##################] | reify:faker: http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/faker/-/faker-5
```

**UPDATE**

I've just tried to uninstall a random package on the docker terminal of my container, and it gave the same error as when I did npm install

Comment: Why can't you install Node and just use it directly?  (How did you install Docker and VSCode?)

Comment: I'm part of a team (doing an internship actually, so I'm quite new to docker), and my team leader said that we want to run everything through Docker, not locally. Docker I installed through its website then, because of the error I reinstalled through homebrew, also not working, vs code was through the website

Comment: If you can do that, I'd also `brew install node` (or `n` or `nvm`).  The setup you show doesn't seem to need Docker at all.

Comment: I mean, we user the file I showed as Dev (docker-compose-dev), the production file has nginx, oauth2, meilisearch and network set up. I just don't get it why does it work locally with npm install but doesn't work inside docker the npm install, and if done locally npm install, then docker compose dev up works

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **Dockerfile** alongside with **docker-compose** file, it will make your life much easier. Remove your node modules in your local machine.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'


services:
  docusaurus:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    tty: true
    ports:
      - '8080:3000'
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - .:/app
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:20

WORKDIR '/app'

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["npm","run","start"]
```

Comment: as I said before, when I do 2 volumes `volumes: - /app/node_modules - .:/app` it works, but I need the node_modules local because I use them with husky in the pre-commit to github

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

It's weirder than I thought,

Any, and I mean ANY docker compose up that I do, that has `npm install` will give me this error, so I thought something was wrong with my MAC, so I wiped out my macbook and installed the OS again but the error persists... And no, its not error with all of my projects because my team leader tested on his mac and it worked normally, without npm, and because it's happening only with me, I could always do npm install before docker compose up, but the problem is, there's another project of ours that I simply can't make it work, and I think its associated to this error... My mac, as I said was wiped out, so all my programs were installed in their last/stable versions, including my OS (ventura 13.4.1)

Comment: ur mac is m1 chip?

Comment: nops, intel core i5